# Regex Replace issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to use regex replace method to replace `xxx="yyy"` pattern of text in given string like.

My pattern is : `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.;:|_-]+="[a-zA-Z0-9.;:_-]+\"/`

Code:

```
var userinput = '<div id="c16430" style="color:red;" class="css-btn">';         
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.;:|_-]+="[a-zA-Z0-9.;:_-]+\"/;
userinput = userinput.replace( pattern, "Replaced..." );
```

But it is not working... [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xw9Bu/3). What is wrong?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The operator `^` is used to say that you're search at the beggining of the subject, in your case, it have not to be used because you're search any place of the string.

Comment: Anyway, everytime you need to deal with regex with JavaScript test it on [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: I would recommend you re-tag this "javascript" instead of "jquery"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

1. You are trying to match the start of the input, using `^` at the start
2. You are not using the global flag `/g` at end, so it would only replace the first match.

This will work:

```
var pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9.;:|_-]+="[a-zA-Z0-9.;:_-]+\"/g;
```

[Here is your updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/xw9Bu/4/)

Comment: Didn't like Muse but you deserve +1 haha

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: Ha! I only usually get "btw, Muse are awesome!", but thanks for seeing past your hatred ;-)

Comment: @musefan haha i'm just kidding.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified for you. As stated this could match false input, not knowing how strict your input is.

```
var pattern = /[^ =]+="[^"]+"/g;
```

or ignore non-word characters

```
var pattern = /[^\W]+="[^"]+"/g;
```

or stick with the original idea, the `i` modifier is used to perform case-insensitive matching.

```
var pattern = /[a-z0-9_.|:;-]+="[^"]+"/ig;
```

Comment: Actually, your regex will match false positives. Consider this input: `<div id="c16430" style="color:red;" class="css-btn">="a"</div>`. Of course, we don't know how strict the input html is in the OP's case, so it may work perfectly well for them... this is why I avoided trying to improve the regex, and just pointed out the problems with the OP's example

Answer (score 0):

It is perfect

```
/\s[^=]+\=\".*?\"/g
```